# Java Mail method not yet implemented mimemessage

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Getting error as "method not yet implemented mimemessage"

While trying to send email

```
   protected static void addAtachments(String[] attachments, Multipart multipart) throws MessagingException, MessagingException {

    for (int i = 0; i <= attachments.length - 1; i++) {
    String filename = attachments[i];
    MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

    attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
}}



  protected static void sendMessage(List<String> recipients, String subject,
                              String messageContent, String from, String[] attachments)
    throws MessagingException, MessagingException {
boolean debug = false;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_PORT);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
            }
        });

session.setDebug(debug);

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
message.setFrom(addressFrom);

for (String recipient : recipients) {
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(recipient));
}

message.setSubject(subject);
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(messageContent, "text/html");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
addAtachments(attachments, multipart);

message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not yet implemented
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:89)
at uk.co.newsint.bp.reg.report.Main.sendMessage(Main.java:84)
at uk.co.newsint.bp.reg.report.Main.main(Main.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: Try using the MimeMessageHelper:      MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
     MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");

Comment: Do you solve the problem?I try using the MimeMessageHelper: MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage(); MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");But still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that the java mail dependency is below
1,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>`
</dependency>
```

because there is another jar include the the `javax.mail.*`
the package is below 
2,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-spec-j2ee</artifactId>
    <version>1.4-rc4</version>`
</dependency>
```

the solution is replace the second dependency with the first one

Comment: How to replace the second dependency with the first one?

Comment: I found geronimo-spec come from activiti-engine.I can not replace it.I am using activiti. @user6586945

Answer (score 0):

You've made some of the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  The JavaMail FAQ also has other examples that might help you.

It's not clear that any of this has anything to do with the exception you're getting.  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Does the application also fail if you run it outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes it fails outside IntelliJ also. javax.mail 1.4.5

Comment: Need more details of your environment.  When you run it outside of IntelliJ, how do you run it?  What's in your CLASSPATH?  What JDK are you using?  What operating system are you using?  Do you have j2ee.jar or javaee.jar in your CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0):

Use message.addRecipients() instead, which is implemented. Method without "s" at the end is not implemented by JAVAMAIL API REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION. See sources downloaded from

https://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/directory/source